# how to get an array from two arrays with the same size of the first array in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, logic

I want an array containing true and false values with the same size of the `administrator` array

```
$scope.result = [];
angular.forEach($scope.administrator, function(option) {
  angular.forEach($scope.Administrator, function(admin) {
    if (option === admin) {
      $scope.result.push(true);
    } else {
      $scope.result.push(false);
    }
  });
});
```

here suppose `administrator` array contains `[a,b,c,d,e,f]` And `Administrator` array contains `[c,d]` so that I could find my result array with value `[false,false,true,true,false,false]`.

Comment: I think that the best approach for you to do this is: `$scope.result = new Array($scope.administrator.length).fill(false);` and then iterate over the `$scope.Administrator` getting the index of the values in the `$scope.administrator` array when it exists. See in this fiddle with pure JS, you just need to adapt it to angular: https://jsfiddle.net/0gy6vcwL/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use plain old JavaScript for this:

```js
var administrator = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];
var Administrator = ["c", "d"];

var result = administrator.map(a => Administrator.some(b => a === b));

console.log(result);
```

Notes:

- [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) iterates over every element of the array it is called on, and returns an array with the same number of elements, transformed through the function passed.
- [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) checks to see if any element in the array it is called on returns true for the function given.

Combining the two, we get an array of elements in `administrator` where the value indicates whether the element is in `Administrator`.

Note that having two variables/property names that differ by case is arguably a bad practice. Consider renaming one of them.

Comment: thanks it worked ^_^ and yes i will take care of those variable and property thanks for the advice again....

Comment: Glad it helped. [Do remember there are some things you can do to thank answerers on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).